# Only works if I run it in debug

Tags: android, json, asynchronous, android-asynctask, okhttp

I'm trying to get JSONData, and if I run it in Debug mode, it works, but if not It won't work... I think think that I have a problem with this asynchronous thing, but I don't know what is wrong. Please help I'm trying to get this done for 2 days and nothing will work...

```
 public static final String SZABAD_EU = "SZABAD_EU";
public static Collections collections = new Collections();
CollectionsAdapter adapter;

@InjectView(R.id.archivumReyclerView)
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_archivum);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);

    setSzabadEuMusoroks();

    adapter = new CollectionsAdapter(this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
}

public void setSzabadEuMusoroks(){
    if (isNetworkAvaible()){
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://1956.osaarchivum.org/api/items?collection=13").build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                alertUserAboutError();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                final String jsonData = response.body().string();
                Log.v("JSONDATA", jsonData);
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                parseData(jsonData);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.e("JSONEXCEPTION", "Exception caught: ", e);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    alertUserAboutError();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.network_unavaible_message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

private void parseData(String jsonData) throws JSONException{
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonData);
    SzabadEuMusorok[] szabadEuMusoroks = new SzabadEuMusorok[jsonArray.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        SzabadEuMusorok szabadEuMusorok = new SzabadEuMusorok();
        JSONArray elementTexts = jsonObject.getJSONArray("element_texts");

        JSONObject titleObject = elementTexts.getJSONObject(0);
        szabadEuMusorok.setTitile(titleObject.getString("text"));

        JSONObject subjectObject = elementTexts.getJSONObject(3);
        szabadEuMusorok.setSubject(subjectObject.getString("text"));

        JSONObject mainObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("files");
        szabadEuMusorok.setAudioURL(mainObject.getString("url"));

        szabadEuMusoroks[i] = szabadEuMusorok;
    }
    collections.setSzabadEuMusoroks(szabadEuMusoroks);
}
```

Comment: What does not work? No Json? Different string? Error when parsing?

Comment: My Array remains null. It won't set it.

Comment: But jsonData is the same than in debug?

Comment: In debug everything works, from getting the jsonData to parsing. If I run it, it will crash later, because of the NullPointerException, because the Array is set to null...

Comment: You need to use logs or Toast to check what's going on.

Comment: Okay the problem is that It startes the adapter too early, before my jsonData file gets even "downaloaded". So the Array stays null and crashes out because of the 0 length

Comment: What do the logs say? Is onResponse() or onFailure() called for example? You should be able to figure that out. Insert a Log.d() each line you will see what's going on.

Comment: Isn't this almost the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39669804/why-is-this-skipping-the-onresponse-method

Answer (score 0):

Please check this solution [(source code)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5gn9p81xh8chipx/TouchTest.zip?dl=0)